# How to write a c program for connecting to MySQL server and executing an SQL query?

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I need to write a C program that connects to a MySQL server and executes an SQL query from a text file having a single query, in linux platform.

I am doing C programming for a while
and also have elementary understanding in SQL.

Now my queries:

For this what are the packages i need to install in my linux system?

How can i do this(programming wise)?

Please give me a starting point where i could begin.
Sample codes, links of sites covering this topic and other study materials will very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install a C compiler and the libmysql development files for your distro. After that you use the [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html) in your code, and link with the appropriate libraries when building.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write a C program that connects to a MySQL server and
>   executes an SQL query from a text file having a single query, in linux
>   platform.

If this is really *all* your program needs to do, and nothing else, it is already written ... you can use the mysql client:

```
mysql < my_file.sql
```